# Assigning unique ID to records based on certain deference between values in consecutive rows using loop in r

Tags: r, function, loops, dplyr, data.table

This is my `df` (data.frame)

```
Time <- c("16:04:56", "16:04:59", "16:05:02", "16:05:04", "16:05:11", "16:05:13", "16:07:59", "16:08:09", "16:09:03", "16:09:51", "16:11:10")
Distance <- c(45,38,156,157,37,159,79,79,78,160,78)
df <-as.data.frame(cbind(Time,Distance));dat
```

```
       Time Distance
16:04:56       45
16:04:59       38
16:05:02      156
16:05:04      157
16:05:11       37
16:05:13      159
16:07:59       79
16:08:09       79
16:09:03       78
16:09:51      160
16:11:10       78
```

I need to assign an ID to each record based on two conditions:

1. If the absolute difference between two consecutive rows of the Time column is 1 minute and
2. If the difference between two consecutive rows of the Distance column is 10.

Only when both conditions are satisfied then should assign a new ID.

Results should be like this

```
       Time Distance ID
16:04:56       45  1
16:04:59       38  1
16:05:02      156  1
16:05:04      157  1
16:05:11       37  1
16:05:13      159  1
16:07:59       79  2
16:08:09       79  2
16:09:03       78  2
16:09:51      160  2
16:11:10       78  3
```

Thanks to all who contribute any thoughts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change `Time` column to `POSIXct` format. Take difference between consecutive rows for `Time` and `Distance` column and increment the count using `cumsum`.

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  mutate(Time1 = as.POSIXct(Time, format = '%T'), 
         ID = cumsum(
   abs(difftime(Time1, lag(Time1, default = first(Time1)), units = 'mins')) > 1 &
   abs(Distance - lag(Distance, default = first(Distance))) > 10) + 1) %>%
  select(-Time1)

#       Time Distance ID
#1  16:04:56       45  1
#2  16:04:59       38  1
#3  16:05:02      156  1
#4  16:05:04      157  1
#5  16:05:11       37  1
#6  16:05:13      159  1
#7  16:07:59       79  2
#8  16:08:09       79  2
#9  16:09:03       78  2
#10 16:09:51      160  2
#11 16:11:10       78  3
```

**data**

```
df <-data.frame(Time,Distance)
```